# Why is this fetch promise-loader not showing result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch

In this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/promise-loader-forked-jscp9?file=/src/App.js)

It's loading like 20 `fetch` `promises` into an `array` and then watching them resolving with a progressbar.

What I don't understand is why in the `makeQueryablePromise` the
 `console.log('inside makeQueryablePromise ',  value);` return `undefined` but in the `fetch` it's not - `console.log('inside fetch ', data))`. `makeQueryablePromise` is having the same `promise`??

Here's a print screen showing log output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: ops wrong codesandbox, I Edit ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```js
  const makeRequests = useCallback(function() {
    return Array.from(Array(promises)).map(() =>
      fetch(URL)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => console.log('inside fetch ', data))
    );
  }, []);
```

The latest callback returns `undefined`, because `console.log` returns nothing, so you loose data.

To solve this, return data:

```js
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("inside fetch ", data);
          return data;
        })
```